# Viewport meta tag width=device-width doesn't work on Android 4.2?

Tags: android, viewport, scaling

I'm building a responsive website. To get the website fit in the mobile browser window, I added the following meta tag in headers :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

This works fine under my S5 default browser.

However, it doesn't work correctly under my S3 default browser => the zoom level is too high (about x2).

I tried adding scaling values like this but it did not solve the issue :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`

I noticed that on my S3, the following works but breaks the site on my S5 :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5">`

How can I get it working on both phones ?

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Try use JavaScript to detect Android version and manipulate meta. This worked for me. Changing width= doesn't give me consistent result.

```
 viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
 viewport.setAttribute('content', "width=device-width, initial-scale=" + window.devicePixelRatio + ", maximum-scale=" + window.devicePixelRatio + ", minimum-scale=" + window.devicePixelRatio);
```

However, be aware that changing scale may result some positioning issue when percentage is used instead of pixel.